# I Cant Run EXE File Outside of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, executable

I appreciate that this question has probably been answered before, but I can't find the solution to my problem.

This is that I can't run my **C#** program by double clicking it in windows explorer. I have tried to run the release and debug versions, but no luck. The program runs without errors or warnings inside VS. I have tried completely rewriting my project in a different solution and it still doesn't work. When I do try to run it, it uses about `75MB` in the `RAM` but then closes. A window comes up saying **"Sending information to Microsoft"**.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I've tried making another project with just a form and nothing else
It runs ok inside VS but when I run the executable from windows explorer it launches but comes up with "GUI has stopped working" when you click on the close button. GUI is the name of the app. This happens with all of the projects that I make from now.

Comment: look in the event viewer

Comment: Are all of the dependent dlls and config file in the same location as the .exe?

Comment: Are you run exe file from bin folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, there was a problem with visual studio or windows. I was running a version of windows 10 but after the update that came on the 06/01/16 it works OK now.
My guess is that it was a problem with the universal windows extension in visual studio

Update:

As of about 7 months later visual studio is working very well on my new computer with windows 10. I also use the latest version on vs which may have been my problem Because my old machine was that: old. It may not have been compatible with the latest software.

Comment: I can confirm that windows 10 actually has some problems running EXEs after I built them. Even with this update mine is still not working and I have all the files.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you are missing something vital which your EXE depends on. It is present when you run the application from the IDE, but not when you run it from Explorer.

Are you running it from the directory which it got compiled to? This is normally under your project, under "bin\Debug" or "bin\Release". If not, then the odds are that you are missing a file which is in that folder. Copy all the files (and any subfolders) to where your EXE lives, and that should fix the issue.

Another possibility is that you need a file which the IDE can find, but Windows cannot.

Debugging issues which cause a crash without a callstack are always tricky. I'd suggest that you add some logging to your app, so you can see what is going on prior to the crash. If the issue is caused by your code, then logging will help to find it.

Or, even quicker and dirtier, throw up a messagebox before every line. Give each one a unique message, and you can then investigate the code around the area of the last messagebox that you see before the crash.